# Set Opacity using CSS on pie-chart in Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Currently i am facing a problem that i need to set Opacity manualy on pie-chart using Highchart. The following solution works fine if you know what color you wish to assign to the slice. But if the color is picked from a palette which is generic, there is no way to give the opacity. It always takes 0. For  Can anyone help me with this.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
         pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true,
                    color: 'rgba(150,100,50,0.1)'
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `opacity` by using `attr` method:

```
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var points = this.series[0].points;

                points[1].graphic.attr({
                    opacity: 0.4
                })
            }
        }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/59mye8kn/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr